# Binary Matrix Reduction in CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, nvidia, pi

I have to traverse all cells of an imaginary matrix `m * n` and `add + 1` for all cells that meet a certain condition.

My naive solution was as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void calculate_pi(int center, int *count) {
    int x = threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.x;

    if (x*x + y*y <= center*center) {
        *count++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int interactions;
    printf("Enter the number of interactions: ");
    scanf("%d", &interactions);

    int l = sqrt(interactions);

    int h_count = 0;
    int *d_count;

    cudaMalloc(&d_count, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(&d_count, &h_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    calculate_pi<<<l,l>>>(l/2, d_count);

    cudaMemcpy(&h_count, d_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_count);

    printf("Sum: %d\n", h_count);

    return 0;
}
```

In my use case, the value of `interactions` can be very large, making it impossible to allocate `l * l` of space.

Can someone help me? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I don't understand your question -- you have an "imaginary" matrix (presuming that means that it doesn't actually exist, not that it is complex), and then you want to conditionally increment entries in that matrix -- i.e. you want to change entries in a non-existent matrix. How can that possibly work?

Comment: With all due respect, @talonmies, you have completely missed the O/P's tricky idea to use a **`{threadIdx,blockIdx}.x`** for indirect mapping ( not mentioning for the moment the state of the **`<<<  >>>`**-*Shevron*-operators' actual parameters used ) the `[x,y]`-values for a (normally immensely large trial/error) pi-generation algorithm ( a classical schoolbook example in the early C/S courses ) and yes, imagination is a legal expression for situations, where a subject need not be instantiated into a real being and yet be a legitimate object of interest and further work with  :o)

Comment: I used the term imaginary array because I don't want to instantiate an matrix for example 50,000 x 50,000. I read about the Reduce technique, it would solve my problem, but if I get it right, I'll always need a giant array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 2 problems with your code:

1. Your kernel code will not work correctly with an ordinary add here:

   ```
   *count++;
   ```

   this is because multiple threads are trying to do this at the same time, and CUDA does not automatically sort that out for you.  For the purpose of this explanation, we will fix this with an `atomicAdd()`, although other methods are possible.
2. The ampersand doesn't belong here:

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(&d_count, &h_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
              ^
   ```

   I assume that is just a typo, since you did it correctly on the subsequent `cudaMemcpy` operation:

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(&h_count, d_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   ```
3. This methodology (effectively creating a square array of threads using `threadIdx.x` for one dimension and `blockIdx.x` for the other)  will only work up to an `interactions` value that leads to an `l` value of 1024, or less, because CUDA threadblocks are limited to 1024 threads, and you are using `l` as the size of the threadblock in your kernel launch.  To fix this you would want to learn how to create a CUDA 2D grid of arbitrary dimensions, and adjust your kernel launch and in-kernel indexing calculations appropriately. For now we will just make sure that the calculated `l` value is in range for your code design.

Here's an example addressing the above issues:

```
$ cat t1590.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void calculate_pi(int center, int *count) {
    int x = threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.x;

    if (x*x + y*y <= center*center) {
        atomicAdd(count, 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int interactions;
    printf("Enter the number of interactions: ");
    scanf("%d", &interactions);

    int l = sqrt(interactions);
    if ((l > 1024) || (l < 1)) {printf("Error: interactions out of range\n"); return 0;}
    int h_count = 0;
    int *d_count;

    cudaMalloc(&d_count, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_count, &h_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    calculate_pi<<<l,l>>>(l/2, d_count);

    cudaMemcpy(&h_count, d_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_count);
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err == cudaSuccess){
      printf("Sum: %d\n", h_count);
      printf("fraction satisfying test:  %f\n", h_count/(float)interactions);
      }
    else
      printf("CUDA error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1590 t1590.cu
$ ./t1590
Enter the number of interactions: 1048576
Sum: 206381
fraction satisfying test:  0.196820
$
```

We see that the code indicates a calculated fraction of about 0.2.  Does this appear to be correct?  I claim that it does appear to be correct based on your test. You are effectively creating a grid that represents dimensions of `lxl`.  Your test is asking, effectively, "which points in that grid are within a circle, with the center at the origin (corner) of the grid, and radius `l/2` ?"

Pictorially, that looks something like this:

[image]

and it is reasonable to assume the red shaded area is somewhat less than 0.25 of the total area, so 0.2 is a reasonable estimate of that area.

As a bonus, here is a version of the code that reduces the restriction listed in item 3 above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void calculate_pi(int center, int *count) {
    int x = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;

    if (x*x + y*y <= center*center) {
        atomicAdd(count, 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int interactions;
    printf("Enter the number of interactions: ");
    scanf("%d", &interactions);

    int l = sqrt(interactions);
    int h_count = 0;
    int *d_count;
    const int bs = 32;
    dim3 threads(bs, bs);
    dim3 blocks((l+threads.x-1)/threads.x, (l+threads.y-1)/threads.y);

    cudaMalloc(&d_count, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_count, &h_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    calculate_pi<<<blocks,threads>>>(l/2, d_count);

    cudaMemcpy(&h_count, d_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_count);
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err == cudaSuccess){
      printf("Sum: %d\n", h_count);
      printf("fraction satisfying test:  %f\n", h_count/(float)interactions);
      }
    else
      printf("CUDA error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    return 0;
}
```

This is launching a 2D grid based on `l`, and should work up to at least 1 billion `interactions` .

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about these atomic functions. About Kernel, I made another small mistake:
...
`int xc = x - center;`
`int yc = y - center;`

`if (xc*xc + yc*yc < center*center) {`
...

Comment: And about the approximate Pi value, it should look like this: `printf("PI: %lf\n", 4.0 * h_count / (l * l));`